# String to array of integer

Tags: arrays, list, python-3.x, integer

I have a string `'[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]'` and I would like to convert to get only the int such that i obtain an array of integer of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

How do I do that? I tried using `map` but unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strip` for remove `[]`, `split` for convert to `list` of `values` which are converted to `int` in `list comprehension`:

```
s = '[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]'
print ([int(x.strip('.')) for x in s.strip('[]').split()])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Similar solution with `replace` for remove `.`:

```
s = '[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]'
print ([int(x) for x in s.strip('[]').replace('.','').split()])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Or with convert to `float` first and then to `int`:

```
s = '[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]'
print ([int(float(x)) for x in s.strip('[]').split()])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Solution with `map`:

```
s = '[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]'
#add list for python 3
print (list(map(int, s.strip('[]').replace('.','').split())))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```